# div has margin bottom on top of another div with margin top, only 1 margin

Tags: css, margin

I have one div on top of the other.  The top div has `margin-bottom: 10px`, the bottom div has `margin-top: 10px`, but there is only 10px of space between the two divs.

Live example: http://jsbin.com/efugok/1/edit

Html with Css:

```
<div style="margin-bottom:10px; background: #e6e6e6;" id="one">one</div>
<div style="margin-top:10px; background: #ccc" id="two">two</div>
```

Rendered:

[image]

Comment: That's margin collapsing: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is called margin collapse. It is a per-spec behavior. **[Read more about it.](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins)**

Basically, when 2 vertical margins overlap, only the largest one is taken into account. Give any of the elements a margin of `20px` to fix it.